# Lag in animations after updating Expo SDK and Reanimated in React Native Expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, lag, react-native-reanimated, metro-bundler

I have a React Native Expo app that utilizes Reanimated to animate bar charts, allowing them to move up and down. After updating the Expo SDK from version 48 to 49 and Reanimated from 2.14.4 to 3.3.0, I've noticed a significant lag in these animations. This lag is mainly evident when using the Metro bundler, but when I deploy the app using eas update, the lag is barely noticeable. I've seen people having similar problems due to safe-area-view but i do not use this.

I expected the animations to remain smooth after the updates, given that they were working fine before. I'm now in a dilemma: Should I just accept the lag, or should I consider downgrading the versions? Is there another solution that I might be overlooking?

Comment: I have the exact situation as you, updated the same packages and on Android the animations are stuttering like crazy. Did you find the root cause or a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your animation to use latest hooks from Reanimated 3 ?

The version 3 has significant changes to the use of hooks like `useAnimatedScrollHandler`, `useAnimatedReaction`, ...
I had animation that were not running properly because of that (mostly animation linked to scroll event) and I corrected it by using latest hooks.

Also, I replaced every variable used in animation with `useSharedValue` and `useDerivedValue` (I was using `useRef` / `useState` sometimes)

Finally, be careful with the worklet you run your animations on (check out `runOnUI` / `runOnJs` from reanimated documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ive tried to follow your suggestions but nothing has helped unfortunately. I'm starting to think i just need to build a better "bar chart component". Ive made a new post where i describe my problem in greater detail: React Native Reanimated - Seeking Alternative Approach for Achieving "Counting Effect" in Bar Chart Component.